# What are the advantages of a photonic crystal versus a liquid crystal or piezoelectric grating tunable optic filter?

Tags: piezoelectric-effect, photonics

I want to design a tunable optical filter that can quickly change from being a red light filter to being a blue light filter. For this purpose, I am wondering about photonic crystal tunable optical filters might be better than liquid crystal tunable optic filters.

We wish to deflect either red, green or blue laser pointer beams aimed at commercial aircraft cockpit windows with a notch filter. The desired switching frequency is on the order of 10's of MHz. The desired switching time is on the order of 1 microsecond. The desired filter bandwidth spans the red, green or blue visible light wavelengths with tunable notches of 2 to 10 nanometers(nm). The attenuation of the optical filter should be less than 10dB.

Would you know why photonic crystal tunable optic filters described in Channel drop filters in photonic crystals (Fan et al, 1998) reports nearly perfect optical transmission in the visible light wavelength passband while LiCHI – Liquid Crystal Hyperspectral Imager for simultaneous multispectral imaging in aeronomy (Goenka et al, 2015) reports 20 to 25% optical transmission loss in the visible light wavelength passband?

With regards to Goenka et al 2015, 
1. Is it possible to improve upon it's 20 to 25% optical transmission loss in the visible light wavelength passband?
2.Is the manufacturing cost reasonable? I realize that Indium Tin Oxide is expensive because Indium is a rare earth, but is it possible to substitute graphene electrodes for indium tin oxide electrodes in the design? If not, what could we do to address the manufacturing cost issue.
3.I noticed this design uses nematic liquid crystals rather than ferroelectric liquid crystals which are reputed to have better switching speeds and transient response time. Is there a reason that this paper chose nematic liquid crystals which are reputed to be less costly?
4. I was wondering whether it might be easier to use a piezo based grating. Please look at Wong et al's IEEE paper "Analog Piezoelectric-Driven Tunable Gratings With Nanometer Resolution" which use electromechanical stretching by thin-film piezoelectric actuators. Does this method have a limited switching speed?

Thank you.

Comment: A question post is generally required to contain one question, yours asks multiple highly technical questions and it unlikely that someone with the right set of knowledge will answer all of them. Having worked in optics there are many different options for tunable filters, highly dependent on application and acceptable cost. Your question is well researched, but it is missing requirements related to your design; Switching time, switching frequency, desired filter bandwidth, expected light power, attenuation/distortion/frequency shifting requirements etc.

Comment: @crasic, Thank you for your comment. We wish to deflect either red, green or blue laser pointer beams aimed at commercial aircraft cockpit windows with a notch filter. The desired switching frequency is on the order of 10's of MHz. The desired switching time is on the order of 1 microsecond. The desired filter bandwidth spans the red, green or blue visible light wavelengths with tunable notches of 1 kilohertz. The attenuation of the optical filter should be less than 10dB. Thank you.

Comment: @1KHz notches at visible frequency? You are asking for tuning that is finer than the natural line width of many hyperfine atomic transitions, this is an unphysical requirement unless I am misunderstanding your meaning. For the benefit of anyone that may want to answer could you update your question with this information?

Comment: @crasic,Thank you for your comment. The desired tunable filter bandwidth spans the red, green or blue visible light wavelengths with notches of 2nm to 10 nm. Thank you,

Comment: This may be a better match for Physics SE

Comment: @Brian Drummond, I posted this topic to Physics Stack Exchange a week and  few days ago and it was voted off-topic and put on hold and finally deleted by the Physics Stack Exchange community today. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the proposed answers based on my discussions with Rochester Institute of Technology Professor Zhaolin Lu,

A. Would you know why photonic crystal tunable optic filters described in Channel drop filters in photonic crystals (Fan et al, 1998) reports nearly perfect optical transmission in the visible light wavelength passband while LiCHI – Liquid Crystal Hyperspectral Imager for simultaneous multispectral imaging in aeronomy (Goenka et al, 2015) reports 20 to 25% optical transmission loss in the visible light wavelength passband?
  The reason that Dr. Goenka's filter reports 20 to 25% optical transmission loss in the visible light wavelength passband is that there is a tradeoff between high on-off ratios and narrow bandwidth for tunable optical filter. So, we should not try to encompass red, green or blue wavelengths simulataneously.

With regards to Goenka et al 2015, 1. Is it possible to improve upon it's 20 to 25% optical transmission loss in the visible light wavelength passband? The tradeoff between high on-off ratios and narrow bandwidth for tunable optical filter requires narrow bandwidth tunable optical filters.

2.Is the manufacturing cost reasonable? I realize that Indium Tin Oxide is expensive because Indium is a rare earth, but is it possible to substitute graphene electrodes for indium tin oxide electrodes in the design? If not, what could we do to address the manufacturing cost issue. 
  Graphene is still a laboratory curiosity. As a result, it is still impossible to fabricate 1 square foot graphene electrodes to be placed in a commercial aircraft cockpit window.
3.I noticed this design uses nematic liquid crystals rather than ferroelectric liquid crystals which are reputed to have better switching speeds and transient response time. Is there a reason that this paper chose nematic liquid crystals which are reputed to be less costly? 
      Nematic liquid crystals were chosen in Dr. Goenka's paper because they were less costly than ferroelectric liquid crystals as well as their superior tuning range.

4. I was wondering whether it might be easier to use a piezo based grating. Please look at Wong et al's IEEE paper "Analog Piezoelectric-Driven Tunable Gratings With Nanometer Resolution" which use electromechanical stretching by thin-film piezoelectric actuators. Does this method have a limited switching speed? 
   The chief limitation of the piezoelectric-driven tunable grating is that it requires large 1 kilovolt(KV) bias voltages.

Thank you.

Comment: @crasic, I thought your comments yesterday were scientifically excellent. May I ask you to comment on my answer? Thank you.